# Appcelerator Alloy - Build failed iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have a simple Hello World! app. It seems to run on my Android Device and emulator. If I want to run it on my iOS simulator the build fails. I have Xcode Version 7.2.1 installed.

Error message:

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileC build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug-    iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MediaModule.o Classes/MediaModule.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

Comment: What TiSDK version?

Comment: I have version 6.0.1.GA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specified you use TiSDK 6.0.1 and xcode 7.2.1 you have an incompatible combination.

Always look at the [Titanium Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix) for exactly this reason. In the xCode section it says you need at least xcode 8.0 for it to work. If you want to stick with xcode 7 you can go up to Titanium 5.5

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm all new to Appcelerator, this was a great help.